# HTML Form Post handling

Tags: html, forms, post

I have a form as detailed below. It uses a post method to send data to `getUsername.php`. This file echoes some JSON results from mysql db.

Am wondering how do I grab this data? When I hit submit it navigates to the file and displays the JSON. I want to grab the JSON and stay on the same page or move to a different one!

I have kept the php file simple because the data is also used for returning data to my android app.

```
<div class="well bs-component">
      <form id ='formLogin' action="http://localhost/getUsername.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Sign In</legend>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input name='email' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input name='password' type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this cannot be done from a form. I instead used jquery post function to return data